# Why does Pniel have two spellings?

Tags: names, geography, vayishlach, spelling-variants

In [Parshat Vayishlach](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=15554&p=3), the place where Yaakov is named Israel is named פְּנִיאֵל (Pniel) by Yaakov, and then one verse later it is called פְּנוּאֵל(Pnuel). Why are these two alternate spellings so close to each other?

Comment: A yud means one time deal,a vav means more than one time